# dynamically adding script tags to angular app

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, amd

ZI'm building an app where based on user preferences/configuration, I'll be loading different modules into the page.

To accomplish this, when the page loads, I run a script which builds a list of script-tags and adds all those tags to the body of the page. I also build a dependency injector list, and include the dependencies when the app is loaded.

I'm delaying app load using by putting

```
window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";
```

and then after the script tags are added, I run

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function(){
          angular.resumeBootstrap();
      },1000);
});
```

I have two problems. 
First of all, for some reason, if I include angular.js in the configuration file, I get errors referring to angular not being found.

I can see that angular is being downloaded to the browser, but I'm guessing it's a timing issue, as angular takes longer to download than many of the other files.

I was going to just put angular in a regular script tag, but then I found that one of the modules I'm loading requires jQuery and jQuery UI, both to be loaded before angular, so that means more files loaded as scripts, and possibly not needed for that user.

I looked at using require.js and passing the config params to

```
requirejs.config.paths = //the custom built list from the users configuration file
```

But, from what I understand, that would also mean I'd need to wrap all of my modules in

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'angular', 'otherModule'],
function   ($, angular, otherModule) {
    // my module stuff here
});
```

Any other suggestions on how to accomplish this? Is there a better AMD than require.js? 
I'd post all my code here, but I don't think it would help as the problem is coming from the browser downloading the files after the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

RequireJs is the best AMD implementation as far as I know.

If you want to specify your modules, you'd better to wrap your moduls in `define` calls:

```
define(['jquery', 'angular', 'otherModule'],
function   ($, angular, otherModule) {
    // DO NOT FORGET TO RETURN YOUR MODULE!
});
```

Also, why don't you start your applicaiton on domReady? You may use [this requirejs plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload).

Here is a basic requirejs configuration for your case:

```
requirejs.config({
   paths : {
      jquery : 'libs/jquery',
      jqueryUi : 'libs/jqueryui',
      angular : 'libs/angular'
   },
   shim : {
      angular : {exports : 'angular', deps : ['jquery']},
      jqueryUI: {exports : '$', deps : ['jquery']}
   },
   map : {
      '*' : {
         domReady : 'require-plugins/domReady'
      }
   }
});


requirejs(['domReady!', 'angular'], function(document, angular) {
  //Thank to domReady!, this callback executes on domReady events. And no need in jquery or angular:)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, Can you explain what you mean about starting on domReady? Angular already does that for me (as far as I know). I've got a few reasons to stay away from require.js. One of them is that for using external modules, that means I need to wrap those modules in requirejs as well, and when they are updated, it means that I need to go back in and update them again. With the script I've written, I just include the module in my config script, and everything gets included properly, with the exception of angular, and jquery needing to be loaded directly.

Comment: @pedalpete I mean, that domReady plugin allows to start bind requirejs callback to domReady event without using angularjs or jquery. As I understood from your question, your script tags may differ for diferrent users and situation when there is not jquery or angularjs is possible.